# How can I make a Guid primary key using MVC Code First Entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to make a one-to-one relationship between the `aspnet_Users` table and my own entity, `Player`. To accomplish this, I added a Guid:

```
public class Player
    {
        public Guid ID;
        // ...
```

However, this isn't automatically becoming the primary key, as I intended. How can I coerce this column to become the primary key?

**Update:**
After looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138027/ef-code-first-foreign-keys), I added this to my `Player` class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class Player
    {
        [Key,Required]
        public Guid ID;
        // ...
```

But still, when I try to do a @foreach in my View,  I get the error " EntityType 'Player' has no key defined"

Comment: At a guess, Code First might require that you use properties, not public fields. At least all the blog posts I've read on it refer only to properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `{get; set;}` to make it a property.